# Rigid body Cell Fracture Explosion

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

When i use cell fracture or subdivision in blender with ridgid body physics. It explodes. How can this be solved?

Comment: Could you please add a little more details as to what is actually going wrong?  Some screenshots [or a GIF](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) would be really helpful.

Comment: Now, I know from experience that the cell fracture addon explodes if you fracture it too much and there are left over single vertices or edges. Try searching for single edges or vertices.

Answer (score -1):

I would first make sure all your RB objects and passive objects have their scale applied ....  ctrl A ....scale.

I would also make sure each objects origin is set to geometry
ctrl..alt...shift C .... origin to geometry.

Posting a blend file would help to troubleshoot other issues that may be occuring.